# Angular nested directive ordering

Tags: css, angularjs, angularjs-directive

i am having a hard time finding any information on the ordering of directives and their updating of css properties.

for example, i have two directives, one to set an element to full screen height, and one to align content vertically.

```
app.directive('fullscreenElement', function() {
    return { 
        restrict: "A",
        link: function(scope,element,attrs){    
            $(element).each(function(){
                $(this).css('height', $(window).height());
            }); 
        }
    };
});

app.directive('alignVertical', function() {
    return { 
        restrict: "A",
        link: function(scope,element,attrs){
            var height = $(element).height();
            var parentHeight = $(element).parent().height();
            var padAmount = (parentHeight / 2) - (height / 2);
            $(element).css('padding-top', padAmount);
        }
    };
});
```

They both work independantly, the trouble is when they are nested, the align-vertical directive doesnt work, im assuming this is because the css height hasn't been set yet? how do i make sure it is set before the alignVertical directive runs? any tips for writing these two directives in a more angular way would be appreciated.

this works:

```
<header style="height:800px">           
    <div align-vertical>
            this content is centered vertically as expected
    </div>
</header>
```

this doesn't work (content doesnt center vertically, even though header height is now fullscreen):

```
<header fullscreen-element>         
    <div align-vertical>
            the header element is now fullscreen height but this content is *not* centered vertically
    </div>
</header>
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out a solution, posting it here in case anyone finds it helpful.

The trick is to use scope.watch and scope.evalAsync to monitor changes of height to the parent container and run them after rendering is complete.

```
app.directive('alignVertical', function() {
return {
    link: function($scope, element, attrs) {
        // Trigger when parent element height changes changes
        var watch = $scope.$watch(function() {
            return element.parent().height;
        }, function() {
            // wait for templates to render
            $scope.$evalAsync(function() {
                // directive runs here after render.
                var that = $(element);
                var height = that.height();
                var parentHeight = that.parent().height();
                var padAmount = (parentHeight / 2) - (height / 2);
                that.css('padding-top', padAmount); 
            });
        });
    },
};
});
```